# Bit Shifting out of register with >>1

Tags: c, bit-shift, atmega

I am using an Atmega 16 on a STK500 Programmer Board.
im Trying to Turn on the leds on DDRA starting on Led0 with 0b00000001 to Led7 with 0b1000000. It seems like i push the set bit out of the register with a >> shift. Shouldnt it just move 1 to the right?
I have this snippet

```
# define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRA=0xFF;
    char leds=0x01;
    while(1)
    {
        if (leds==0x01)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                PORTA=~leds;
                leds=leds<<1;
                _delay_ms(300);
            }
        }
        else
        for (int x=0;x<8;x++)
        {
            leds=leds>>1;
            PORTA=~leds;
            _delay_ms(300);
        }

    }
}
```

it seems like this part

```
for (int x=0;x<8;x++)
            {
                leds=leds>>1;
                PORTA=~leds;
                _delay_ms(300);
            }
```

pushes the bit out of the register, but it should not. am i making a mistake?

Comment: What display do you get and what display do you expect?

Comment: Before you try to make this work on a microcontroller, try it on your computer, just printing out the bits of `leds` in each iteration. You'll quickly see how your expected results differ from what the math is actually doing.

Comment: @Sneftel No. Simply check the actual register value with an in-circuit debugger...

Comment: hint: what is the value of leds after the first time though the while statement. How will that be handled the second time round the while loop? And the else is executed that second time, from what I can see.

Comment: You have some bugs here which are not necessarily related to the problem. Bug 1) You should never use `char` for 8 bit arithmetic, since it has implementation-defined signedness. Use `uint8_t` instead. Bug 2) Your MCU has 16 bit integers and all small integer types will get implicitly promoted to signed `int`. In case `leds` has the MSB led set, 0x80, you invoke undefined behavior by shifting `leds` 8 times left. You invoke implementation-defined behavior by shifting `leds` 8 times right. Cast `leds` to `uint16_t` before shifting, always.

Comment: Also, bare metal microcontrollers should not use `int main (void)`. Who are you gonna return to, the reset vector? And then what, halt and catch fire? This calling convention could needlessly crap up the stack when main is called. Use an implementation-defined form of main such as `void main (void)`, supported by most compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shifting the 1 out in the first loop. And you are not seeing because you update the display before the shift.

At the end of the iteration with i = 0, leds will be equal to 0x02. So the following this logic you get:

```
i, leds (end of the loop)
0, 0x02
1, 0x04
2, 0x08
3, 0x10
4, 0x20
5, 0x40
6, 0x80
7, 0x00
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping the OP could work that out for themself.

Comment: yeah, me updating the display before the shift was my problem. i assumed the leds would indicate which bit is set.

Comment: @barny, sorry I hadn't seen you comment.